# Laravel morpToMany issue

Tags: mysql, laravel, relationship

I have this problem, I try to connect movies and casts through morpToMany, but I get a strange error, I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Movie

```
    public function casts()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Cast::class, 'movie_casts');
    }
```

Cast

```
    public function movies()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Movie::class, 'movie_casts');
    }
```

MovieCast

```
    public function movies()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Movie::class, 'movie_casts');
    }
  
    public function casts()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Cast::class, 'movie_casts');
    }
```

movie_casts table

```
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('cast_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('cast_id')->references('id')->on('casts');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('movie_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('movie_id')->references('id')->on('movies');
```

Controller

```
    public function moviesList()
    {
        $movies = Movie::all();

        foreach($movies as $movie){
            $moviesWithCast = $movie->casts;

        };

        return response()->json(
            $moviesWithCast,
            200
        );
    }
```

Getting this error:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'movie_casts.movie_casts_id' in 'field list'

Answer (score 0):

You are not using a morph relationship, it's a simple M2M relationship :

Movie

```php
    public function casts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Cast::class, 'movie_casts');
    }
```

Cast

```php
    public function movies()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Movie::class, 'movie_casts');
    }
```

why would you take the morph approach ?